# angular add/update json object from user input both attribute and value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I am able to get both attribute name and value from user input

```
{{attribute}} and {{value}}
```

how do i add these to an existing json object

```
$scope.items ={
 name: peter,
 age: 16,
 {{attribute}}: {{value}}
}
```

Comment: is attribute also a user input? If yes then you can trigger a function using ng-change of the input field and set the attribute and value to the object. And if you already know the attribute use ng-model.

Comment: you could use `$scope.items[$scope.attribute] = $scope.value` but why you would want to do this I don't understand.

Comment: i am trying to create a user interface where user can create custom form, means they name their input field labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use bracket notation.

```
$scope.items[$scope.attribute] = $scope.value;
```

Comment: Thanks! didnt know i can do that, great lesson

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/x9mYD2Uo1q57XdX7aiYR?p=preview) for your problem statement,using `ng-change` I've called a function to create the JSON object dynamically when ever user changes anything in the input fields or form.
Below is the look of the controller where we create the JSON object

```
var myApp = angular.module('Test', []);
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.input={};
  $scope.items={};
  $scope.createObj = function(){
    $scope.items['name'] = $scope.input.name;
     $scope.items['age'] = $scope.input.age;
  };

}]);
```

HTML will look like this:

```
<body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h5>Name:</h5>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.name" ng-change="createObj()"/>
    <h5>Age :</h5>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.age" ng-change="createObj()"/>
    <pre>{{items}}</pre>
  </body>
```